# Getting "Invalid user credentials supplied" when sending request with Guzzle PHP

Tags: php, postman, guzzle

I am sending the absolutely same request to an endpoint with Guzzle PHP and Postman extension for Chrome.

When sending the request with Postman - I do recieve the response, but when I am sending the same request with Guzzle I get "Invalid user credentials supplied".

I have the Auth type Basic and supply the same username/password for both apps. Here is the code that I use for guzzle:

```
    $credentials = [$client->api_username, $client->decrypted_password, 'basic'];

    $result = $this->client->get($fullUrl, [
       'auth' => $credentials
    ]);
```

I have dumped the credentials - it is the correct array. I have double checked the [Guzzle docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#auth). Funny thing is that when I am trying to send request for another user for the same endpoint - I do recieve the correct response, which made me think, that I might have typos in credentials - but I have rechecked - and even copy pasted from Postman - still cant recieve the response :/

Answer (score 1):

Would you love to share what your variable `$credentials` has as data?
In case try the code below it was tested and works:

```
$client  = new Client();
$this->results = $client->request('GET/POST', $uri, [
  'debug' => true,
  'query'   => $arguments,
  'auth'    => [$username, $password],
  'verify'  => false
])->getBody();
```

And if you ask about the other arguments such as `verify`, this property tells guzzle to disable certificate verification.

Read below: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#verify

For more information about `auth`: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#auth

Comment: tried "verify" => false, still same problem :/. When setting debug to true - getting and error related to CURL, which is I think happens because I am on a windows machine.

Comment: the guzzle error message is "Invalid user credentials supplied" though I can use the same when sending via Postman

Answer (score 0):

Could you compare the `Authentication` header from Postman and from Guzzle? If you get an exception from Guzzle, you can get it like `$exception->getRequest()->getHeader('Authentication')`.

Comment: They are the same. I think the issue is somehow related to SSL of Guzzle